# $2^b-1$ does not divide $2^a+1$,how can I show it?

Tags: number-theory

$$\text{ If } a,b \geq 3, \text{ show that } \  2^b-1 \text{ does not divide } 2^a+1$$

How can I do this? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Have you tried by induction? It's easy to see that if $b>a \geq 3$ then $2^b-1$ does not divide $2^a+1$ since its larger. So assume $b \leq a$ for example, set $b=a$. does $2^a-1$ divide $2^a+1$? does $2^{a-1}-1$ divide $2^a+1$? Induction works nice here.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Suppose $2^b - 1$ divides $2^a + 1$. Note that $b\le a$, so we may write $a = qb + r$ where $0\le r \le b-1$. What can you say about $(2^{qb} - 1) \mod (2^b-1)$?

Comment: Why do we know that $b \leq a$ ??

Comment: @esque Maybe if we use induction and suppose that the basis is 3 for a and b $( a = 3, b = 3)$ then we have $2^3-1 = 7$ and $2^3+1 = 9$. Maybe that's how $b \leq a$ ? I'm also new at this and had a very crummy prof.

Comment: @evinda Suppose $b>a$, then $2^b-1 \geq \underbrace{2^{a+1}}_{= \ 2^a+2^a} - 1 > (2^a + 2) -1 = 2^a +1$, which contradicts the initial assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b\ge3$ and let $a$ be minimal with respect to
$$2^b-1\;|\;2^a+1.$$
Assume that $a<b$. Then we have $2^b\le 2^a+2<2^b+2$ which forces $(a,b)\in\{(0,1),(1,2)\}$, contradicting the choice of $a$ and $b$. Therefore we know that $2^{a-b}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now $2^b-1$ divides $2^a+1-2^{a-b}(2^b-1)=2^{a-b}+1$, contradicting the minimal choice of $a$.